# How to effectively compare different type of ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

For example

The pricing of `c6g.medium` ($0.0340) is almost 3x the `t2.micro` ($0.0116) instances, however I am seeing that `c6g.medium` only have 1 vcpu which is the same with `t2.micro`.

So how would you compare the instance performance of `c6g.medium` cpu (AWS Graviton2 processors) with whatever t2 is using for its cpu?

Is `c6g.medium` more efficient than 3 `t2.micro` instance if the t2 used all its cpu credit all the time?

Can I assume all `c6g` cpu has 3x more thread/core than all `t2` cpu?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ Choose ec2 as per your needs and do a comparision

Answer (score 0):

The difference between t2 and c6g instances is the burstable nature of the t2 instance.

A t2.micro is cheap because of the way the credit system works, where you can't always use 100% of your CPU and can only burst there periodically. With the c6g instance, you will be able to use 100% of your CPU at all times if you so desire. The other difference is memory, your t2.micro instance has 1GB memory whereas the c6g.medium has 2GB of memory allocated, which also increases the price.

Then there is the CPU architecture which is ARM, which won't be able to run x86 compiled applications natively and some applications will need to be recompiled specifically to run successfully.

The major differences between the instance types can be found on the bottom of the EC2 instance types page:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types

If you need to do a real-world performance comparison of your application, the best way would really be to spin up some instances and run benchmarking / load testing on them to see which one performs better in your specific scenario.